# Present Modal ViewController via TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a main `tabBarController` and would like to present a `viewController` `modally` when a certain `tabBarItem` is tapped.

I am loading the `viewControllers` in my `tabBarController` as...

```
func setupViewControllers() {
    self.tabBar.isHidden = false

    if let firstVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first") as? FirstViewController, let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as? SecondViewController, let thirdVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third") as? ThirdViewController, let fourthVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fourth") as? FourthViewController, let fifthVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fifth") as? FifthViewController {

        let firstNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC)
        let secondNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
        let fourthNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: fourthVC)
        let fifthNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: fifthVC)

        firstNavController.tabBarItem.image = image
        secondNavController.tabBarItem.image = image
        fourthNavController.tabBarItem.image = image
        fifthNavController.tabBarItem.image = image     
        thirdVC.tabBarItem.image = image

        tabBar.tintColor = nil

        //Load tabBar viewControllers
        viewControllers = [homeNavController, postNavController, plusMenuVC, meetupNavController, profileNavController]
    }
}
```

I then conformed the `tabBarViewController` to the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to invoke the method...

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2, let thirdVC = viewController as? ThirdViewController {
        thirdVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        thirdVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        present(thirdVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    } else { return true }
}
```

The above however never gets triggered. I tried setting in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.delegate = self
```

I tried setting the root navigation controllers and its ancestor `tabBarController` delegate to self.

Nothing seemed to work and I hope someone can guide me as I've been unable to debug and find an existing solution...

**UPDATE**
So I created a `dummyThirdVC` to replace the `thirdVC` in the `setupViewControllers()` function. In the `dummyThirdVC`, I conformed to `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and in `viewDidLoad` I set the `self.tabBarController.delegate = self`. Then I took the `delegate` method and entered it into this `dummyThirdVC`, where inside this `delegate` method, I instantiated the real `thirdVC` to present.

The `delegate` method finally triggers properly, but my issue now is, the `dummyThirdVC` and its view must first load and appear for the `delegate` to be set and triggered thereafter.

How can I not show the `dummyThirdVC` and immediately just present the instantiated, real `thirdVC`? I had tried `dummyThirdVC.viewDidLoad()` in my `setupViewControllers` function to no avail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your check is wrong. You're checking for `selectedIndex` to be 2, but the `selectedIndex` 's value will always be the actual tab bar's selected index, and not the index that is going to be selected, so you're basically never going to reach `selectedIndex` as 2.

You also cannot present a view controller that is already active, and `thirdVC` is already active in your tabBar, thus you will get an error. A workaround for this is to use a viewController as placeholder for image and title in the tab bar and instantiate another one for presenting.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController is ThirdViewController {
        let vcToPresent = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third") as? ThirdViewController
        vcToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        vcToPresent.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        present(vcToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i have two issues. My first is the delegate method never gets triggered regardless of the check. My second is I am trying to present this thirdVC modally over any VC that's already being presented - is this an issue if I have this placeholder VC and then instantiate another one?

Comment: 1. You said you tried debugging it and print out the delegate of the `tabBarViewController`, is it the same object as `tabBarViewController` ?

Comment: 2. If you use the same instance of thirdVC in both the tab bar and modally presentation, you will receive an error because thirdVC is being active in the tab bar, and you're trying to present a view controller that is already active.

Comment: The issue was I had assigned the tabBarController delegate within one of the rootVCs of the tabBarController...printing and comparing objects was what uncovered this for me, ugh...